# FFmpeg Windows MP4 - remove specific frames

Tags: video, ffmpeg, encoding, software

I have a movie - movie.mp4. I wish to remove/delete specific contiguous frames from movie.mp4 which are located somewhere near the middle.
Specifically, total frames in movie.mp4 = 33,595.
I would like to remove frames 19,965 to 19,982
Using FFmpeg - I guess this is question of creating two temp files which exclude the deleted frames and then concatenating the two temp files back into one. My knowledge of FFmpeg is limited so I son't know how to do this. 
Also if I wish to exclude other chunks ( frames e.g. 19,561 to 19581, etc) can this be achieved efficiently in one coding string.
Any suggestions greatly appreciated. Many thanks.

Comment: Is audio present?